# /proc/cpuinfo shows a single core under VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, cpu

My host machine is Windows 7, running an Intel Core i5 Processor.

The Task Manager shows that I have 4 boxes under the Performance tab, which I assume to be 4 cores.

However on my OEL guest (on VirtualBox) /proc/interrupts only gives me a CPU0 column, suggesting that I only have one core.

Is this occurring because I am using virtual software?

```
[root@khadija ~]# cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 42
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz
stepping    : 7
cpu MHz     : 2265.248
cache size  : 6144 KB
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 5
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc up rep_good nopl pni monitor ssse3 lahf_lm
bogomips    : 4530.49
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:


[root@khadija ~]# uname -a
Linux khadija.ahlanwsahlan.net 2.6.39-400.23.1.el6uek.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed May 8 16:37:12 PDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the number of processors that are devoted to the guest VM under its settings dialog.

[image: ss#1]

Doing so will definitely allocate more CPU cores to the guest VM.

[image: ss#2]

Comment: Unfortunately this option is grayed out on my Oracle VM Virtualbox. VT-X is set as enabled in the BIOS.

Comment: Another thing, I have been reading about ESXi recently. If I were to set up ESXi and then run virtual servers on top, would those virtual servers register all of my CPU cores as ESXi runs on 'bare metal?'

Comment: @khadija - is your guest running? You have to stop it to get it un-grayed out. Also your host system has to have a CPU that allows it. Once you change it you can start the guest back up.

Comment: @khadija - I don't understand your 2nd Q here.

Comment: Great it is working, thanks.
What I meant was that if I were to remotely access a server running ESXi, would the system specifications show that it had taken full advantage of the hardware? As in all CPU cores would be present etc.

Answer (score 2):

The hypervisor presents a certain number of cores to the guest OS. I am not familiar with VirtualBox but I assume that it is quite similar to KVM/QEMU where you can configure the amount of cores (even above the number of physical ones).

Have a look at the settings of your VM.